# ios fmdb load db from file

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, sqlite, fmdb

I use sqlite and fmdb wrapper. My code for load db is this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"biscuit.sqlite"];
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
```

I add `biscuit.sqlite` to my project, but this code create new file instead open existing one. How can I load this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to read data from your database, try to use the code below:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"biscuit" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

If you need read/write access, you have to copy your database to a writable user folder first.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"biscuit.sqlite"];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
if (!success) {

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"biscuit.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create writable DB. Error '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"DB copied.");
    }
}else {
    NSLog(@"DB exists, no need to copy.");
}
```

Comment: This will get your app rejected, use a different path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896757/apps-must-follow-the-ios-data-storage-guidelines-or-they-will-be-rejected-in-app

Comment: Could I just drop the ".sqlite" suffix in document folder? @luqmaan