# Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected in app that contains .sqlite3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdocumentdirectory

I created an ebook app and my app contains a lot of images and pdf files

I was putting the downloaded images in /Library/Caches and putting the pdf files and .sqlite3 file in /Documents

now my app is rejected and this is the reason

```
2.23 Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected
```

Is this means that I have to move all what in /Documents to /Library/Caches? 
If I let the .sqlite3 file in /Documents, will the app reject again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.23 means that you should only put stuff into /Documents that cannot be re-downloaded from the internet. i.e. user-generated files. Everything that CAN be re-downloaded should be in Library/Caches.

The reason for this rule is that /Documents gets backed up and users don't like if you waste their precious iClould backup space.

Comment: The .sqlite3 file is not downloaded so I putted it in /Documents and other pdf files and images are downloaded and I made their path to be Library/Caches.. your answer means that I'm right, isn't it?

Comment: @Cocoanetics In addition to whether the data is user-generated, there's one other factor to consider: How important is it that the content is available offline? E.g. for a travel guide that is likely to be used abroad (-> expensive roaming), or for a dictionary, podcast app, etc., it might be appropriate to put it in a directory that's not automatically purged by the system (i.e. not Caches) and set the "do not backup" flag.

Comment: True, though Offline is arguably an edge case. In our iCatalog apps we are putting the catalogs into Caches because the infamous "Cleaning" tends to happen only very seldomly and if it does then the catalogs are probably a lesser priority than other valuable user content. - Having said that I personally think that only very rarely does downloadable content deserve the same level of deletion protection as user data.

Comment: @user1553381 it depends how difricult the sqlite DB is to regenerate. If that is just a local copy of online data then it shpuld go into Caches as well. If it holds info that the user does not want to lose (read flags, annotations, etc), then documents is the rit place. - having said that: you should never put large files into databases, iOS 5 gives you external file references. there you CAN put a file into an NSData but internally CoreData will put it into an external file. I guess that you were using up too much backed up Documents space without good reason.

Comment: You know what users ACTUALLY dislike? Having to download all their stuff over and over every time the app gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to put the downloaded PDFs and databases into the Caches directory. An alternative would be to use the "do not backup" attribute, as described here: [Technical Q&A QA1719 - How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html).